# Critique my method for predicting easter product sales from daily data

Tags: regression, categorical-data, moving-average, moving-window

I hope this question benefits the site as well as myself. Thanks ahead for your time.

So I work for a company that sells (among a lot of things) personalized items specifically for Easter - stuffed bunnies made of cloth with a child's name on it, colored Easter baskets with personalization, etc.

Perhaps Obviously Easter often falls on different months, so I looked at daily data, used a modified formula to find how far away from Easter any particular day was, and then did a 7 day average of the Daily sales to account for outliers in the general seasonal trend. (EDIT: I should also note we only sell these items around Easter, not during, say, September. This made ARIMA difficult to work with.)

Then I selected a window of 62 days prior to Easter and 31 days after Easter, combined 5 years of data of this 94 day period, and included 4 dummy variables for each year.

Then I did a simple regression to get the coefficients of the dummy variables. To predict into the future, I did a simple linear or 2nd order trend analysis of the dummy coefficients, and converted that into a percentage of the most recent year of sales (i.e. next year is predicted sell 20% more than the previous year).

If that was unclear, I have uploaded a few screen caps to  https://i.stack.imgur.com/njQd1.jpg